# Upload & Link an Image with php

Tags: php

I know this should be really simple, but im having trouble getting this to work right, basically i want to have an image upload box that uploads an image and then puts the new url into a mysql database. Anyone have any advice on how to do this, as i may be having developer block but im over complicating it in my head :P Thanks

Comment: "new url" = path/name of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Uploading files using php.](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some kind of LAMP server, the uploaded files will be placed in a temporary directory. You will have to move them from there to their final destination and I usually give the moved files a new file name to avoid any security problems. Of course the original file-name is available so you can keep it as well, either as a file-name or as an entry in a database.

What are you precisely having problems with?

Comment: I know how to upload the file, but im just trying to think would it be as easy as upload file to /upload

so it uploads /upload/example.jpg

then get the name of the file and insert /upload/example.jpg to image table?

im just thinking what i do to get the name to the db :)

Comment: Do you have problems getting the name or adding an entry to a database?